# How does one move/copy context from one task to another

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I use a new agile practice called "interrupt-driven development" (IDD) ;-) in which I'm juggling tasks a lot.  I'd like to use Mylyn to help maintain context.  By context, in case it's not clear, I primarily mean the set of filtered files in the explorer, and secondarily the set of open editor windows.

My problem is that I forget.  I get an email, I start working on the issue, and 10 minutes later, I realize that I forgot to create a new task or activate an old one.  By that time, I've opened much/most of the context that I need.

When I get to this point, is there any way to move or copy the files I mistakenly now have in one task's context to another task's context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click anywhere in the task editor of the source task (or right click the source task in the task list) and select "Copy Context To". A dialog will let you select the target.

Comment: This doesn't provide as fine-grained control as I'd hoped, but is a lot better than what I knew of.  Thanks!

Comment: you can adjust the context of a task by opening the "Context" editor tab. There you can remove things from the context. Maybe that helps a bit.